# $\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt3}dx,2<x<5$

Tags: integration

Prove that $\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt3}dx,2<x<5$
$=\sqrt{(x-2)(x+1)}+9\log(\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x+1})+6\sqrt2\log\frac{\sqrt3-\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{2(x+1)}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt3}-2\sqrt3\sqrt{x+1}$

$\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt3}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}(\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt3)}{x-5}dx=\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}\sqrt{x-2}-\sqrt{3(x+1)}}{x-5}dx$

I am stuck here.

Comment: You can always differentiate the right hand side and compare to the integrand. Guess and Check *is* a method ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x-2 = t^2\;,$ Then $dx = dt$ So Integral $$\displaystyle I = 2\int\frac{\sqrt{t^2+3}}{t+\sqrt{3}}\cdot tdt = 2\int \frac{\sqrt{t^2+3}}{t+\sqrt{3}}\cdot tdt$$

Now let $$\displaystyle = 2\int\frac{\sqrt{t^2+3}(t+\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3})}{t+\sqrt{3}}dt =2\int\sqrt{t^2+3}dt-2\sqrt{3}\int\frac{\sqrt{t^2+3}}{t+\sqrt{3}}dt$$

Let $\sqrt{3} = a\;,$ Then Second Integral $$\displaystyle -2a\int\frac{\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}{t+a}dt = -2a\int\frac{t^2+a^2}{(t+a)\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt$$

So $$\displaystyle -2a\int\frac{(t+a)^2-2at}{(t+a)\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt = -2a\int\frac{t+a}{\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt+4a^2\int\frac{t}{(t+a)\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt$$

Now we can write

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{t}{(t+a)\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt = \int\frac{(t+a)-a}{(t+a)\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt = \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}-a\int\frac{1}{(t+a)\sqrt{t^2+a^2}}dt$$

Now Put in second Integral  $$\displaystyle (t+a) = \frac{1}{u}\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle dt = -\frac{1}{u^2}du$$

So $$\displaystyle = -\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2au+4au^2}}du$$

Now Collect all Integral and Using The formula of Type $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}dx$ and $\int \sqrt{x^2+a^2}dx$ etc.